# Some questions about Fitting ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a finitely presented $R$-module. Given a free presentation
$$ R^{\oplus m} \to R^{\oplus n} \to M \to 0 $$
we define $Fitt_k(M)$, the $k$-th Fitting ideal of $M$, to be the ideal generated by all the $(n-k)\times (n-k)$ minors of the matrix representation of the map
$$ R^{\oplus m} \to R^{\oplus n}. $$
This definition makes sense because one can easily show that $Fitt_k(M)$ is independent on the presentation of $M$.

I guess this can be be defined using the exterior algebra instead of minors, could you give me some clues on how I should do that?

Moreover, do you know any good and modern book/paper in which the theory of Fitting ideals is treated?

In particular I'm very interested in statements about the Krull dimension of $Fitt_k(M)$.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Do you assume that $M$ is finitely *presented*? As for a book recommendation: Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry*.

Comment: Yes, I meant finitely presented. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin suggested, a nice reference is

> Eisenbud - Commutative Algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry

The definition of Fitting ideals that can be found there is indeed in term of exterior algebra, and precisely is the following (it consists of 2 parts)

> **Def:** Let $\varphi:F\to G$ be a map of free modules over a ring $R$. We define the ideal $I_k(\varphi) \subset R$ to be the image of
>   the canonical map $$ \Lambda^kF\otimes\Lambda^kG^*\to R $$ induced by
>   $\varphi$ (see the note below for details).

Now we are ready to define Fitting ideals:

> **Def:** Let $M$ be a finitely presented module over $R$, and consider a free presentation $$ \varphi: F\to G \to M \to 0 $$ of $M$ such that
>   $G$ is a finitely generated $R$-module of rank $r$. For every integer
>   $k\geq 0$ we define the $k$-th Fitting ideal of $M$ to be $$ Fitt_k(M) := I_{r-k}(\varphi). $$

The above definition makes sense, since $Fitt_k(M)$ doesn't depend on the chosen presentation, i.e. if we have another presentation
$$ \varphi': F'\to G' \to M \to 0 $$
with $G'$ of rank $r'$ then Hans Fitting showed in 1936 that $I_{r-k}(\varphi) = I_{r'-k}(\varphi') $.

---

**Note:** The canonical map involved in the definition of $I_k(\varphi)$ is obtained in the following way: first by the universal property of exterior algebra, given $\varphi:F\to G$, we have a unique map
$$ \Lambda^k\varphi : \Lambda^k F \to \Lambda^k G $$
and we can thus define the above canonical map as
$$ \Lambda^kF\otimes\Lambda^kG^*\to R, \qquad a\otimes b \mapsto b(\Lambda^k\varphi(a)) $$

Comment: The question about dimension is still open... I'll create another specific question for it