# Krull dimension bound of a Fitting ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, krull-dimension

Given a finitely presented $R$-module $M$ over a ring $R$ one can define, for every integer $k\geq 0$ the $k$-th [Fitting ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_ideal) of $M$, for instance in [this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/583581/3416), using exterior algebra.
$\DeclareMathOperator{Fitt}{Fitt}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}$

Actually, given any free presentation
$$ \varphi: R^{\oplus m} \to R^{\oplus n} \to M \to 0 $$
of $M$, we can describe $\Fitt_k(M)$ as the ideal of $R$ generated by the $(n-k)\times (n-k)$ minors of the matrix representation of $\varphi$.

Do you know if we can say something about the Krull dimension of $\Fitt_k(M)$? In particular I would like to show that (I think the claim is true, but I'm not sure) the codimension of $ \Fitt_k(M)$ in $R$ is at most
$$ (k+1)(n-m+k+1) $$
Do you agree with me that this holds? If so, do you have any suggestion on how to prove it?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical result of Eagon and Northcott says that 
$$\operatorname{height}(I_r(\varphi))\le (m-r+1)(n-r+1).$$ 
Since $\operatorname{Fitt}_k(M)=I_{n-k}(\varphi)$ we have 
$$\operatorname{height}(\operatorname{Fitt}_k(M))\le(k+1)(n-m+k+1).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Abramo J. A. Eagon and D. G. Northcott, *Ideals defined by matrices and a certain complex associated with them*, Proc. Roy. Soc. Ser. A 269 (1962), 188-204.